# Getting url after history.pushState on android with javascript

Tags: android, url, pushstate

My web page loads data with ajax and if page is loaded I change url using window.history.pushState but after change window.location.href on android still returns me previous link (link is changed on url bar). On desktop browsers works fine. There is any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering, it's a bug: 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17471

a workaround would be to manually keep track of the pushState that you do